# code hangs on mysqli_connect

Tags: php, mysql, server, virtual-machine

I am running PHP and MySQL on a VM with Amazon Web Services. I am simply trying to connect to my database, but the PHP code isn't working.

The way I am running the PHP is somewhat roundabout, I am using `elinks` like this:

```
elinks http://localhost/ServerCode/proccesusers.php
```

`proccesusers.php` is a PHP file that has this code:

```
<?php

echo "Connecting to server... <br/>";
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "mm_User", "c01f148554b4a2b", "mm_queue");

echo "Getting queries... <br/>";

.
. (some other code is here)
.

?>
```

I know that PHP is installed correctly because "Connecting to server..." prints out, and I know that MySQL is installed correctly because I can access is through the `mysql -u root -p` command. However, after that message is printed, nothing else happens. There is no error message, and neither does "Getting queries..." get printed.

Just in case, I also ran

```
SHOW DATABASES;
```

and it returned this:

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| accounts           |
| mm_queue           |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
```

so mm_queue is a valid database.

Can anyone help me out with what is going wrong here?

Comment: use error reporting and mysqli_error for the connection, see if anything comes of it

Comment: @Fred-ii- I added echo(mysqli_connect_error()); after the mysqli_connect, it printed nothing. Is that the correct way to report the error?

Comment: It's shown in the manuals http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Note: `mysqli_error($db)` requires a connection argument also.